# Sleep Tracking App connected with google health

Tags: sleep

Do you know if there's an app :

- Dedicated to sleep tracking
- Connected with Google Health

I'm interested in such an application, so if you know one, please share it w/ me.

Thanks.

Rob

Comment: Google is [discontinuing Google Health](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/update-on-google-health-and-google.html) so you may want to look for a different option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [Sleep Bot Tracker Log](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sleep-bot-tracker-log/com.lslk.sleepbot) and [Sleep Logger](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sleep-logger/org.acmelab.sleeplogger).  They don't seem to directly connect to Google Health, but they let you export data (one does CSV, the other doesn't specify).

Comment: I knew both of these apps, but unfortunately, none of the android apps related to sleep seems to connect to google health

Comment: I've never used Google Health.  Will it not let you import data via csv?

Comment: Huge +1 for mentioning Sleep Bot... so interesting to look at sleep data.

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing an open-source app called ElectricSleep, and it will eventually have this sort of functionality. It is getting close to going into beta.

project website: http://code.google.com/p/electricsleep/

Comment: great ! I'll have a look tonight

Comment: the beta launched yesterday. you need android 2.2 and an accelerometer. search for "electricsleep" in the market and help test it so I can push out cooler features soon!